# Repair filesystem permission

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, chmod

I accidentally executed

> sudo chmod -R 777 /

I was actually trying to change a specific folder permission recursively, btw i did stop the command before it changed everything.

But now, i can't execute for example

> sudo

Every time i try to sudo something it throws me this error:

> effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

Btw i know i can use `chown -R root:root /usr/bin` where sudo is located, but of course i don't have the permissions to do this.

So, how can i revert this process? Or at least save the `sudo` file without reinstalling everything?

The system is still connected to the internet and seems to work fine besides the sudo issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, how can i revert this process?

You do not. At least it will be hours of work if you want to reset every file to what it is suppose to be.

I would advice to use the live dvd to make a backup of your personal files and settings and do a re-install without a format (this should replace all the system files and keep your personal files (the backup is for insurance)).

Comment: And apps for example, would they keep working? After backup and reinstall without format of course. 3rd party apps.

Comment: @NeoVe most likely you need to re-install them (but they will keep the settings you set them on)